# Clipping a formula to make a nice compliment

Tags: crop, path-clipping

I just found a nice cartoon and wonder if this is possible with LaTeX as well.

If you draw "128 \sqrt{e 980}" on the blackboard (sqrt written with the root character) and erase the approximately upper half, you get "I love you".

[image]

Has anyone a nice suggestion how to clip the text from the following document?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

{\large \[ 128 \sqrt{\text{e}980}\]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I noticed someone has down voted this question. But not me for sure!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `tikz`:

[image]

Also with a more condensed font:

[image]
[image]

## Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\VAdjust}{0,-0.15ex}%
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {$\scalebox{1.5}{128} \sqrt{\text{e}\scalebox{1.5}{980}}$};
\draw [fill=gray!10, fill opacity=0.9, draw =none] 
    ($(A.west)+(\VAdjust)$) -- 
    ($(A.east)+(\VAdjust)$) -- 
    (A.north east) -- 
    (A.north west) -- 
    cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

For the condensed version

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usepackage[condensed,math,light]{iwona}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path % <---- Change to clip for the clipped version
node[
     xscale=0.7,yscale=1.5,
     append after command={([yshift=-0.5pt]a.west) rectangle (a.south east)}
    ] 
(a) at (0,1) {128$\sqrt{\!\resizebox{1ex}{0.7ex}{e}\text{980}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @percuse: Sorry, can't use chat: [http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/chat-stackexchange-not-showing-graphics](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/chat-stackexchange-not-showing-graphics).

Answer (score 5):

### Method 1

Just 4 fun with PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\Huge $\displaystyle 128\sqrt{\text{\LARGE e}980}$}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\wd\IBox,\ht\IBox)
\rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(\wd\IBox,\ht\IBox)
\psclip{\psframe[linestyle=none,linewidth=0](0,0)(\wd\IBox,0.45\ht\IBox)}
\rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\endpsclip
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Method 2

With graphicx. Note that it must be compiled with either `pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex` or `xelatex -shell-escape filename.tex`

```
%filename.tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{temporary.tex}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle 128 \sqrt{\text{\scriptsize e} 980}$
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{pdflatex temporary}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[trim=0 0 0 6.2,clip]{temporary}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `adjustbox` package allows you to clip or trim anything in the same way `\includegraphics` allows it for images. It uses the same key=value interface and allows for the same options, e.g. `trim=<left> <bottom> <right> <top>,clip`, but also provides a shorter version `Clip=<left> <bottom> <right> <top>` key (note the capital `C`) which can even be used multiple times. You can use the original dimensions of the content as `\height`, `\depth`, `\width` and `\totalheight` in the length arguments. However, because they are space separated you need to include a length argument in `{ }` if it ends in a macro (=space eater).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{Clip=0pt 0pt 0pt {.6\height}}% clip away 60% from the top.
$128 \sqrt{e 980}$
\end{adjustbox}
% or \adjustbox{Clip=..}{...}
\end{document}
```

However, the standard math font doesn't do it here, the *e* is too high and the other characters do not build the wanted letters nicely when clipped.

[image: Result]